Unable to withdraw undelegated stake on Solana devnet
I am using @solana/web3.js to test SOL staking on Solana devnet.
I was able to create a staking account, send SOL to it, delegate the stake to a validator and deactivate the stake. This was all done last week at epoch 797.
The staking account is AricY4xtKQ5tjD7JmLQZYJ8Ln27qQtkpESXDpuS2Umuq
Today at epoch 800 I am unable to withdraw the undelegated stake. I am getting the following error message from the Stake program:  Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111: Error processing Instruction 0: insufficient funds for instruction
I tried with the full stake amount, the stake amount + rent, and smaller amounts down to 1 lamport without success. Withdrawing 0 lamport does not revert though.
I checked the staking account status with solana-cli and this is what I'm getting:
solana stake-account AricY4xtKQ5tjD7JmLQZYJ8Ln27qQtkpESXDpuS2Umuq 
Balance: 0.01228288 SOL 
Rent Exempt Reserve: 0.00228288 SOL 
Stake account is undelegated 
Stake Authority: Gc5FrPQZ88to9fBK7xL8pwgzKdaZJcHykZ7b7Q4GXEWV 
Withdraw Authority: Gc5FrPQZ88to9fBK7xL8pwgzKdaZJcHykZ7b7Q4GXEWV

So it seems the staking account is indeed undelegated.
Anyone has an idea of why I am still un able to withdraw from this account?
Thanks in advance.
